# Как инициализировать map множеством значений сразу?

Tags: c++, map

Имеется `std::map<int, int> move_map;`. Нужно инициализировать его значениями. Можно ли как-то быстро это сделать? Знаю, что только можно сделать так:

```
move_map.emplace(1, 92);
move_map.emplace(3, 97);
move_map.emplace(26, 78);
move_map.emplace(62, 87);
move_map.emplace(22, 76);
move_map.emplace(27, 28);
move_map.emplace(29, 96);
```

Если ли что-то наподобие `{1,2,3,4,5,2,6,21,4}`?

Comment: ага. `std::map<key,type> move_map = {{3,97},{26,78}};`

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` имеет [несколько конструкторов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map), позволяющих задать сразу множество значений. В данном случае подходящей является версия (5) со списком инициализации:

```
map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
    const Compare& comp = Compare(),
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

```
std::map<int, int> m = { {3, 97}, {26, 78}, {62, 87} };
```